# Django ListView not working

Tags: python, django, listview, backend

I want to display list of notes on a per user basis. So that the user who has logged in can only see his/her notes. However the listview for displaying all the notes for the logged in user is not working.Is there anything I need to add? Please help!

Views.py

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model=Notes
```

models.py

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subject=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text=models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notes_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class NotesCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Notes
        fields=('title','subject','text')
```

notes_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron container" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);margin-top:2em;">
    <a href="{%url 'notes_create'%}">Add</a>
    <br>
    {%for note in notes_list %}
        <a href="{%url 'notes_detail' pk=note.pk%}">{{user.note.title}}</a><br> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define custom queryset on NotesListView

```
class NotesListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Notes
    context_object_name = 'notes_list'
    template_name = 'name of your template'

    def get_queryset(self):
       return super(NotesListView, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your views.py  normally you add those to your forms.py instead of views.py

I am doing the similar thing with my query filter.I hopes it helps you.

```
queryset_list = Notes.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working. NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: It should be self.user in class based view. There is no open request parameter in that.